# How. if possible, do I create *.jsxbin (export to binary) for jsx ExtendScript files using Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: jsx, extendscript

At present I use ExtendScript Toolkit from Adobe in Windows to only generate the jsxbin file from the jsx files I code using Visual Studio Community 2019 (not VS Code!).  I also handle my C++ Photoshop plugin code and building in VS2019.  I'm aware that I can edit and create the jsx/jsxbin files in VSCode but would like to stay with VS2019 for everything.  If I could easily transfer the build of C++ for the plugin to VSCode I might do that.  I have not found anything about how to do that.

I was told that I could use this [Convert jsx ExtendScript files into jsxbin files using ExtendScript Toolkit](https://github.com/runegan/jsxbin)  but I have no idea how to use it.  I can't get the person who told me about it to help and I can't find contact info for the author.

I appreciate your patience for my running on.

RONC

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary js script and run it with ESTK.
It's easier if you're using a build tool such as Gulp/ Grunt/ Webpack.

Here's a basic sample for a Gulp task on Windows, using NodeJS:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const del = require('del');
const log = require('gutil-color-log'); // OPTIONAL

var myJSFilePath = 'PATH\\TO\\MY\\JS\\FILE.jsx';

exports.encodeToJSXBIN = toJSXBIN;

function toJSXBIN (done)
{
  var jsxbinFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(myJSFilePath), path.parse(myJSFilePath).name + '.jsxbin'), // Will be written in the same folder as your .jsx file
  compilerScriptPath = path.join('FOLDER\\PATH\\TO\\TEMPORARY\\SCRIPT', 'compiler.jsx'),
  estkPath = "PATH\\TO\\ExtendScript Toolkit.exe", // Could be: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit CC\\ExtendScript Toolkit.exe
  estkCommand = JSON.stringify(estkPath) + ' -cmd ' + JSON.stringify(compilerScriptPath),
  compilerScript = "#target estoolkit#dbg\n" +
  "\n" +
  "var jsxbinContent, jsxbinFile;\n" +
  "\n" +
  "jsxbinContent = app.compile(" + JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync(myJSFilePath, 'utf8')) + ");\n" +
  "jsxbinFile = File(" + JSON.stringify(jsxbinFilePath) + ");\n" +
  "jsxbinFile.open(\"w\");\n" +
  "jsxbinFile.write(jsxbinContent);\n" +
  "jsxbinFile.close();";

  fs.writeFileSync(compilerScriptPath, compilerScript);

  exec(estkCommand, (err, stdoutA, stderrA) =>
  {
    if (err)
    {
      log('red', err.toString()); // OPTIONAL
      done();
    }

    del([compilerScriptPath], {force: true}); // Remove the temporary compiler.jsx file

    /*
    - OPTIONAL step
    - single line .jsxbin file
    - you can also replace .jsxbin extension with .jsx if you want
    */
    fs.writeFileSync(jsxbinFilePath, fs.readFileSync(jsxbinFilePath, 'utf8').replace(/[\r\n]+/gm, ''));

    done();
  });
}
```

EDIT #1:

Until you'll familiarize yourself with NodeJS and Gulp or any other build tool, I've made a quick setup you can use.

1. Install NodeJS: https://nodejs.org/en/
2. Open a CMD/ Terminal/ GitBash ( https://git-scm.com/downloads ) in the "Export_to_JSXBIN" sample folder.
3. Install Gulp globally: `npm install -g gulp`
4. Then: `npm install`
5. Put your .jsx/ .js files you want to encode into 'jsx_sources'
6. From the command line type: `gulp encodeJS`

A new folder 'jsx_encoded' will be created which will contain the .jsxbin files with the extension changed to .jsx and all the content formatted to a single line.

You can of course leave the extension unchanged and write the encoded JS in the same folder as your source file, if that suits your needs.

The content of 'gulpfile.js' should be easy to understand.

Ooh... and check the ESTK path (var estkPath), especially if you're on a mac.

**Export_to_JSXBIN** Gulp sample: https://url.io/export_to_jsxbin

Gulp tasks can be launched from your IDE too. I'm sure you can find an extension for this.

Comment: Alex,  Thanks.  I'm going to have to get familiar with node.js etc. as I'm pretty illiterate other than c/c++/js/jsx.  The last two very limited knowledge.  Basically what you are suggesting is that I install node.js then gulp and I should be able to execute your code, with proper changes, from VS2019 and have jsxbin end up in same folder as js code.  So I'll install node.js and all it needs then do gulp.  Correct?  RONC

Comment: I'll add an edit to my answer because of the characters limit in here.

Comment: I think I did as you suggested but I get an error:    C:\Users\RECHM\Google Drive\$$-SYNC\$$Ft_IFt-Split\Export_to_JSXBIN>gulp encodeJS

[00:01:28] Processing: C:\Users\RECHM\Google Drive\$$-SYNC\$$Ft_IFt-Split\Export_to_JSXBIN\jsx_encoded\DComp.jsx
[00:01:30] 'encodeJS' errored after 1.83 s
[00:01:30] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\RECHM\Google Drive\$$-SYNC\$$Ft_IFt-Split\Export_to_JSXBIN\jsx_encoded\DComp.jsx'     The file did not appear in jsx_encoded.  Compiler.jsx contained the complete input file.  RONC

Comment: Is the script written in ECMAScript 5 or 6? For example, does it contain arrow functions? Because Extendscript is ES3 and you'll get an error otherwise.
Also, I presume the path to _ExtendScript Toolkit.exe_ is correct?
If you encode it manually with ESTK, does it throw any errors?

Comment: Script is ES3 but needs includes so I need to modify the gulpfile.js file to us the correct folder for the source and includes not the folder in Export_to_JSXBIN.  You have made things much easier and I appreciate that.  Will be back as soon as I have another attempt.  RONC

Comment: You can automate the includes part too. Check `gulp-include` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-include).

I've updated the .zip archive, so please [download](https://url.io/export_to_jsxbin) it again and do an `npm install` as I've added new Gulp modules.

_'jsx_sources'_ contains a _main.jsx_ and _libs/secondary.jsx_ which is being merged with _main.jsx_.

I also left in _gulpfile.js_ a `replace` if you're using `#include`.

For testing purposes, I'm not deleting the _'jsx_sources_merged'_ folder, but you can uncomment line 65 and remove line 64 from _gulpfile.js_.

Comment: If I have to physically move the includes to one of the folders, this won't work as the includes are in a number of folders under a major folder containing all my jsx files and I don't want to mess with something that works.   It is also getting too complicated for me to understand without a lot of reading.  The original file at top seems more to what I need with using the set input and output locations for my files.  RONC

Comment: `gulp-include` will handle it, you don't have to manually copy anything. Just set the main .js files` paths in the gulp task (line 20). The included files must not be in the same folder, or you can exclude those specific files from the path. As an exercise, move somewhere else the content of _jsx_sources_, update the paths (in and out) in _gulpfile.js_ and run the task again.

Comment: I appreciate your time but this is by far more work on my part than just running ESTK or VSCode to get the jsxbin file.  I'm going to stick with what is working for me.  Hopefully someone else will benefit from your help.  Thanks, RONC